# Consume a WCF service from within a Transformation in SSIS

Tags: wcf, com, ssis

I have a WCF service that I need to consume from within an SSIS Data Flow Transformation, and I'm trying to figure out how to go about that.

I'm aware of the Web Service Task, but that is for Control Flow tasks, and this needs to happen within the Data Flow Transformation.

Note that this service is COM visible, so that's an option if that will be the easiest way to do it.

What are my options?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're using a language (like C#), I'd add that as a label. Also, they totally misspelled your name, too... :P (Of course I'm kidding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never tryed it but perhaps you can call the service from data flow's script component. You can also develop whole new component for SSIS.

I doubt that calling service for each processing record will make your data flow terribly slow and for large datasets probably useless.